# When hapi-auth-basic validate function gets called

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, aurelia-auth

I am using hapijs with hapi-auth-basic and trying to debug using node-inspector.

Implemented example on github page with slight modification to require basic auth on /login path instead of all gets:

```js
const validate = function(username, password, callback) {
  const user = users['john']; //john exists in a user array
  if (!user) {
    return callback(null, false);
  }
  callback(null, true, {
    id: user.id,
    name: user.name
  });
};
...
server.register(require('hapi-auth-basic'), (err) => {
  server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', {
    validateFunc: validate
  });
});
```

```js
{
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/login',
  config: {
    auth: 'simple',
    handler: require('../../public/api/handlers/login.js')
  }
}
```

All other routes set to auth: false. 
I know it applies the 'simple' strategy because if I set the auth to false for /login I hit a breakpoint in the login.js file.

The problem is that I get a 401 on the call and I never get a breakpoint hit in the validate function.

Edit:
Header is sent by client as:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch 
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST 
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:3000 
Origin:http://mac.local:3000
Referer:http://mac.local:3000/ User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0
(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
```

With Content as:

```
{"email":"a.b@com","password":"xcvx"}
```

What I probably missunderstand is the steps in Basic authentication. As a login POST do I need to send an Authorization header? I thought this page sends over the payload to be processed and then if successful all other requests would cary over some token like jwt including an Authorization header.

I am testing out aurelia-auth. The method that makes the [call](https://github.com/paulvanbladel/aurelia-auth/blob/master/src/authService.js#L66) doesn't seem to set any header. Do I need to configure any setting?

Comment: Your validate function gets called here: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-basic/blob/master/lib/index.js#L65. Maybe your 401 is coming from earlier in that file. Are you missing Authorization header or is it in the incorrect format? How are you making requests? Browser? Can you provide a full intact code example to show this issue?

Comment: @MattHarrison you were right. The Authorization header was missing.
github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-basic/blob/master/lib/index.js#L37 is looking for one. Need to check why the client doesn't include one and update the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in my case.

1. I was trying to validate a "login" POST using hapi-auth-basic. Which means that it requires an Authentication key previously set. But it shouldn't work like that. You send over username and password in payload in plain relying on https to cover your tracks. Then server says OK and sends back the auth header with your encrypted identification. Then you use this header to make any calls to 'restricted' areas.
2. I was combining the 'jwt' way with the 'basic' way for no good reason.

And lesson 3. read the github sourcecode!